# Can't start pentaho BI server

Tags: java, pentaho

I'm new to `Pentaho`.
I have downloaded biserver-ce-5.4.0.1-130.zip and run `start-pentaho.bat` but nothing happened after this:

```
DEBUG: Using PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME
DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7
DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "D:\biserver-ce\tomcat"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "D:\biserver-ce\tomcat"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "D:\biserver-ce\tomcat\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7"
Using CLASSPATH:       "D:\biserver-ce\tomcat\bin\bootstrap.jar"
```

I have set `JAVA_HOME` and `PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME` to JDK and JRE 7 path and neither worked.
My OS is windows 8.1.

Comment: Any errors or log files?

Comment: JAVA_HOME is only required..
check whether you have setted your java_home properly or not..
it should be similar to below one.
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45

Comment: JAVA_HOME is set to C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_04

Comment: Define "neither worked." - what URL did you try to access it with? What happened when you did that? More details and maybe we can help.

Comment: Did you check the logs? You should look at catalina.out under d:\biserver-ce\tomcat\logs